# Is this the right way to populate UICollectionView (inside a table view cell) with Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

**Problem: TableView is very slow when scrolling. Looks like my code is not efficient at all.**

So I have a UICollectionView embedded inside a tableViewCell like so (I used [this](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) tutorial to accomplish it.)

[image]

I am using Firebase to populate data into the UICollectionViewCells. I have 3 class folders:

1. TableViewCtrl: Responsible for downloading section titles and then passing some logic to tableViewCell. Here is partial code of the main TableViewCtrl:

   ```
   // 1. DOWNLOAD SECTION TITLES AND THEN CALL RELOADTABLE

   // 2. TableView:
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return featuredCollection.count
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "browseCell", for: indexPath) as! BrowseCell
       cell.configureCell(of: featuredCollection[indexPath.row].typeOfItem, title: featuredCollection[indexPath.row].categoryTitle, bookReference: featuredCollection[indexPath.row].bookReference, spotlightTests: featuredCollection[indexPath.row].spotlightTests, bookUniqueIDsToDownload: featuredCollection[indexPath.row].bookUniqueIDsToDownload)
       return cell
   }
   ```
2. TableViewCell:

   ```
   func configureCell(of type: FeaturedItem, title: String, bookReference: BookReferenceTest?, spotlightTests: [BookReferenceTest]?, bookUniqueIDsToDownload: [String]?) {
       setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(delegate: self, dataSource: self)
   // DOWNLOAD THE BOOK ITEMS (eg. IMAGES, TITLES, ETC) then call self.collectionView.reloadData() 
   }

   internal func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate <D: UICollectionViewDelegate, S: UICollectionViewDataSource>(delegate: D, dataSource: S) {
       collectionView.delegate = delegate
       collectionView.dataSource = dataSource
       let collectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
       let myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.collectionView.bounds, collectionViewLayout: collectionViewFlowLayout)
       myCollectionView.delegate = self
       myCollectionView.dataSource = self
       collectionView.reloadData()
   }


   // Snipit of code that's responsible for downloading book assets:

   func downloadBrowsingBooks(bookUniqueKeys: [String]) {
       let databaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
       databaseReference.child("Kutub/Books/").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
           (snapshot) in
           var books = [BrowsingBook]()
           for book in (snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot]) {
               if bookUniqueKeys.contains((book.key)) {
                   let browsingBookValues = book.value as! [String : AnyObject]
                   let browsingBook = self.createBrowsingBookObject(data: browsingBookValues, uniqueKey: book.key)
                   books.append(browsingBook)
               }
           }
           self.storedBooks = books
           self.collectionView.reloadData()
       })
   }

   internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "booksCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! BooksCollectionCell
           let bookTitle = storedBooks[indexPath.item].title
           let authors = storedBooks[indexPath.item].authors
           cell.configureCell(title: bookTitle, authorNames: authors)
           return cell
   }
   ```
3. UICollectionViewCell:

   ```
   func configureCell(title: String, authorNames: [String]? = nil, imageCover: UIImage? = nil) {
       var authorName = ""
       if let authors = authorNames {
           authorName = authors[0]
           for index in 1..<authors.count {
               authorName += ", \(authors[index])"
           }
       }
       // ....
   }
   ```

From my understanding, here's step-by-step of what's happening:

1. Section titles are downloaded
2. TableView.reload() configures the tableViewCells
3. Inside tableViewCells, firebase downloads images and other book assets (eg. titles, authors, publishers names in text from Firebase database) and calls on collectionView
4. CollectionView configures it's cells.

Again, my ***main problems is that scrolling is very slow and laggy*** with the way that I'm doing this. When I tried different methods (eg. downloading the data and passing it on to tableviewCell) it works but when I add items to Firebase database only section titles show up and not the content inside the collectionViewCells.

Comment: Anyone down to help me with this? :)

Comment: There are two steps 1) Observe Firebase and populate an array with the data. That data is usually stored in that array as dictionaries/classes 2) After the array is populated, reload the tableview, which uses the array as it's datasource. There should be no other interaction with Firebase other than being notified of adds, changes, or deletes, which updates the array. Your tableView:cellForRowAt should not be loading anything from Firebase - only load from the array. When a user taps something in the tableview for detailed information, THEN you hit Firebase for it (situational)

Comment: Oh... and there are a number of calls to setting delegates etc that are unnecessary. Check out the [Firebase iOS QuickStart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios) examples and it will really help tidy up your code.